# excel .save() not working in 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

The following vb.net code works in 2010, but it often breaks in 2007. It's not even consistent.

```
_Application1.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
```

where _Applicatio1n is of type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`

This is the error-code:`0x800A03EC`

The file is not on network drive or anything (which seems to be the common reason based on google search).

Comment: Is the file marked "read only" and do you have edit permissions?

Comment: @ZnArK Dim xl_wbBook As Workbook = Workbks.Open(PathName) <-This is how I'm opening the workbook if it's not already open. I think it opens it as readOnly set to false. Plus it's working fine in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution. The problem was that the vba in excel 2010 was referencing a dll specific to 2010 version of Office (Microsoft Outlook Library 14.0 to be specific.) Once I removed the reference (I no longer needed it), it all worked fine.